# How do I implement this cool accordion slider in React if it doesn't like Jquery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am developing a React web app which could  really use this [accordion slider](http://bqworks.net/accordion-slider/)
the problem is that even if I follow the steps by the creator, my React app  v18 keeps warning of JQuery i.e. $ is not defined, unrecognized <, etc elements of JQuery required to run this slider.

Is there a way to create this accordion slider without the JQuery? I don't need it to slide automartically, users can select the tabs they wish to see.

Thanks

I install jquery using `npm install jquery --save`
then I added the slider scrips to the index.html
then bellow there is a script to initialize the slider

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './blog.css';
import {Article} from '../../components';
import {blog01, blog02, blog03, blog04, blog05} from './imports';
import $ from 'jquery'; // <------- gives an error

const Blog = () => {
  return (
    <><div className='gpt3__blog section__padding' id='blog'>
      <div className='gpt3__blog-heading'>
        <h1 className='gradient__text'>
          Portfolio
        </h1>
        <div id="my-accordion" class="accordion-slider">
          <div class="as-panels">
            <div class="as-panel">
              <img class="as-background" src="assets/slider/image1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="as-panel">
              <img class="as-background" src="assets/slider/image2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="as-panel">
              <img class="as-background" src="assets/slider/image3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="as-panel">
              <img class="as-background" src="assets/slider/image4.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="as-panel">
              <img class="as-background" src="assets/slider/image5.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('#my-accordion').accordionSlider()};
  gives an error ----------->});
      </script></>
  ) 
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: I got told off before for simply sharing links but I hope this might be of some help to you: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-jquery-inside-a-react-component

Comment: You really should read some react documentation. Adding a script tag inside a react component should never happen.